# How can I inject a ui router's url parameter into the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

still learning angular and got a question.

inj ui router config I got this example:

```
.state('content-expertise', {
            url: '/expertise/:expertiseId',
            templateUrl: 'app/content/content.html',
            controller: 'ContentController',
            controllerAs: 'content',
            params: {
                expertiseId: { value: null, dynamic: true }
            }
        })
```

And in my controller I got this code:

```
function StartController($timeout, webDevTec, toastr) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.awesomeThings = [];
    vm.classAnimation = '';
    vm.creationDate = 1494746446244;
    vm.showToastr = showToastr;
```

How can I inject the 'expertiseId' variable from url parameters into the controller?

thx for any help, 
n00n!

Comment: this is angularjs, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$stateParams`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#url-parameters) service to get access over parameters of current `state`

```
function StartController($timeout, webDevTec, toastr, $stateParams) {
    var vm = this;
    console.log("expertiseId", $stateParams.expertiseId)
    vm.awesomeThings = [];
    vm.classAnimation = '';
    vm.creationDate = 1494746446244;
    vm.showToastr = showToastr;
```

Answer (score 1):

`function StartController($timeout, webDevTec, toastr, $stateParams) {`

And access it like so: `$stateParams.expertiseId`.